# Second class of testing.xml doesn't execute

Tags: java, xml, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created 2 separate classes to test a webpage. But, unfortunately when I add them both to the `testing.xml`, only one of them execute and the other doesn't. The browsers open in parallel even after setting them to `preserve-order="true"` `parallel="false"` in the XML. I'm confused as to where I'm doing it wrong.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestServiceNow.loginOne"/>
      <class name="TestServiceNow.loginTwo"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

loginOne is as follows:

```
package TestServiceNow;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import ServiceNow.login;
public class loginOne extends loginTest{
    @Test
    public void test_Login(){
    //Create Login Page object
    objLogin = new login(driver);
    //login to application
    objLogin.loginGurukula("admin", "admin");
    }
}
```

loginTwo is as follows:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import ServiceNow.login;
public class loginTwo extends loginTest{
    @Test
      public void test_Login_Fail(){
          //Create Login Page object
          objLogin = new login(driver);
          //login to application
          objLogin.loginGurukula("admin", "admin1");
    }
}
```

The base class is as follows:

```
public class loginTest {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    File file = new File("C:/Users/gattu_000/Documents/selenium-java-3.0.0-beta2/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver;
    login objLogin;

    @BeforeClass
    public void a() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Before class called");
    }
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup(){
        System.out.println("Before test called");
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/#/login");
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("After test called");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("After class called");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

The results look like
[image]

**After the Edit**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are extending loginTest by both loginOne  and loginTwo. But in loginTest you initialized your driver. That's why two browser are opening. To get around this issue, you can initialize your driver inside a setup method like @BeforeTest or @BeforeSuite. As an example here's a code snippet -

```
 @BeforeSuite
 public void a() {
     driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
     System.out.println("Before suite called");
 }
```

Do other things as usual like before except the initialization part.

**Edit**

I missed something. You are closing your driver at the after test method. To run your tests properly remove the `driver.close()` from your after test method and place it to aftereSuite section.

Comment: Hi, I have tried it the way you mentioned. It opens only one window this time but the second class doesn't run. I have updated my code in the question with the error screenshot too.

Comment: I think you meant "AfterSuite" section is where the driver.close() goes into. That didn't work either.

Comment: How I want it is, It opens the browser, executes loginOne() the closes the browser and then opens a new one to execute loginTwo()..

Comment: for this case you may change your annotations beforeSuite to beforeClass  and afterSuite to afterClass

Comment: That has actually not launched a browser completely. I have attached the screenshot for the update. I'm sure this is a very small issue but, I'm unable to figure it out.

Comment: I fixed it finally. :) The problem was with the XML, I created 2 separate Tests and and run the code for correct execution.

Answer (score 0):

The XML is supposed to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestServiceNow.loginOne"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="Test1">
    <classes>
      <class name="TestServiceNow.loginTwo"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

To launch the browser twice, we need to have 2 separate tests. (Possibly, this may be one of the solutions out of many)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Selenium Test Suite">
<test name="Selenium Test Suite">
<classes>
<class name="packagename.classname1"/>
<class name="packagename.classname1"/>
</classes>
</test> 
</suite>
```

Which is proper. If you are getting null point don't use driver in all the class. because of that only you are getting null pointer i guess.